# Unset while running recursion

Tags: recursion, clear, assignment

I am trying to run a recursive definition while at the same time clearing previously found values, so my memory is not completely consumed. I found this: [How to clear parts of a memoized function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19536/how-to-clear-parts-of-a-memoized-function)  But it does not seem to be what I am looking for.  I want to clear memorized values, while the recursion is running. I thought I could do something like this:

```
Block[{$IterationLimit = $RecursionLimit = ∞},f [m_]:= f [m] = f [m-1]+f [m-2]

f[0]=0

f[1]=1

If [m - 3 > 0, Unset[f[m-3]]]
```

But it does not work. I realize I could just use `Fibonacci[n]`, but I am doing this to try to learn *Mathematica* not to study the Fibonacci sequence.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: `DownValues[f] = (DownValues@f)[[3 ;;]]`??

Comment: Sidenote, you aren't localizing `RecursionLimit` there. Plus, the variables are `$RecursionLimit` and `$IterationLimit` with a `$`

Comment: A long time ago I played with using memoization while limiting memory use.  It's described [here](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php).  Search for memoization on that page.

Answer (score 9):

If I've understood the question correctly, you need to put the `Unset` inside the function definition, e.g.

```
mem : f[m_] := (
  mem = f[m - 1] + f[m - 2];
  If[m > 3, Unset@f[m - 2]];
  mem)

f[0] = 0;
f[1] = 1;
```

Now you can compute, say, `f[50]` and get the speed advantage of memoization, but only ever keeping the two values required for the next iteration.

```
f[50]
(* 12586269025 *)

?f
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

I realize that the Fibonacci sequence is merely an example, but since it is an example it might as well serve to show other approaches.  Please see: [Fibonacci Sequence Generator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31593/121).  In addition to those methods here is a [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nest.html) variation:

```
nx[{a_, b_}] := {b, a + b}

g[n_] := First @ Nest[nx, {0, 1}, n]

Array[g, 9, 0]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21}
> ```

Only the last two values are kept for the next calculation, just like Simon's code.  This is also quite a general method as you could perform any operation on the last *n* values.  (Of course a method keeping all values, such as `NestList` or `FoldList`, would be better if you are building the fully array.)

Comment: Very good to know, thank you!