# How to do memoization together with evaluation of a complicated function

Tags: downvalues, memoization

**UPDATE 2**: much shorter version

Given a list of paired indices {i, j}={{1,2}, {3,4}, …}, I need to first evaluate a rather complicated function `test[i,j,x]` (because it's too computationally costing) and then assign each copy to a function named after {i, j} with memoization. Specifically, I need an expression (as elegant as possible, though timing is more important) which effectively does the following things:

```
f12[x_]:=f12[x]=Evaluate[test[1,2,x]]
f34[x_]:=f34[x]=Evaluate[test[3,4,x]]
…
```

Note that in this example `Evaluate` has no effect (due to memoization), but **I want it to be done first!**

---

**UPDATE 1**

Thank @SimonWoods for proposing a `Function` approach and @m_goldberg for proposing a replacement rule approach. However both approaches are not quite satisfying in their own ways. For the `Function` approach, I confirmed that in the simplest MWE (with no indices in `f`) it does assign `x^2` instead of `test[x]` to `f[x]`:

```
(f[x_] := f[x] = #) &[test[x]]
?f
```

But when I want to create `{f12, f34, …}` I have no idea how to generalize this approach because the existence of the extra `#` ruins the function definition

```
(ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x_] := ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x] = #) &[test[x]] @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
?f12
```

The replacement rule approach does address this issue as shown in @m_goldberg's answer. However as I said the function `test` also depends on `{{1,2}, {3,4}, …}`. Specifically, one can think of this complicated function as either

```
test[i_, j_, x_]:=Module[{some stuff}, some complicated operations which use {i, j} and return an expression in x]
```

or

```
test12[x_]:=Module[{some stuff}, some complicated operations which return an expression in x]
test34[x_]:=Module[{some stuff}, some complicated operations which return another expression in x]
```

and so on. In other words, I would like to assign the evaluated result of `test12[x]` (or `test[1,2,x]`) to `f12[x]`, that of `test34[x]` (or `test[3,4,x]`) to `f34[x]`, so on so forth. **(I should have made this point more transparent. Apology.)** But the replacement rule approach seems to fail at this requirement: the code

```
((ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x_] := 
   ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x] = 
    expr;) /. expr -> test[#1, #2, x] &) @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

does not give `f12[x_]:=ToExpression[f<>ToString[1]<>ToString[2]][x]=test[1,2,x]`; it gives `expr` instead. So both approaches still do not meet my need yet.

---

My goal is to create a bunch of functions `{f12, f34, …}` on the fly for later calculation. Those functions involve a pre-defined `Module` (let me call it `test`) which gives a rather complicated expression. For simplicity let us first consider the following example:

```
(ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x_] := 
ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x] = x^2;) & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

This example defines functions `f12[x]` and `f34[x]` to be `x^2` with memoization which can be easily seen by using `Downvalues`:

```
f12[#] & /@ Range[2]; DownValues[f12]

{HoldPattern[f12[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f12[2]] :> 4, HoldPattern[f12[x_]] :> 
(ToExpression["f" <> ToString[1] <> ToString[2]][x] = x^2)}
```

The last element of `DownValues[f12]` is of crucial importance as it tells us the expression of `f12[x]` is `x^2`.

Now let me use a different approach. I define a function using `Module`

```
test[x_] := Module[{a}, a = x; FullSimplify[Log[Exp[a^2]], Assumptions -> a > 0]]
```

which essentially gives me `x^2` upon evaluation. Follow the same strategy let us define `f12` and `f34`:

```
(ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x_] := 
 ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x] = test[x];) & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

and look at again the `Downvalues` of `f12`:

```
f12[#] & /@ Range[2]; DownValues[f12]

{HoldPattern[f12[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f12[2]] :> 4, HoldPattern[f12[x_]] :>    
(ToExpression["f" <> ToString[1] <> ToString[2]][x] = test[x])}
```

Note that now the last element of `DownValues[f12]` involves the function `test`. However this is not what I want! The reason is that as I mentioned above in my calculation `test[x]` is a rather complicated expression (which depends on the indices `{{1,2}, {3,4}, …}`) simplified within the `Module`, and I would like to assign the simplified expressions to `{f12, f34, …}` instead of computing them in situ. I tried

```
(ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x_] := 
 ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x] = 
  Evaluate[test[x]];) & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

But `DownValues[f12]` simply gives me

```
{HoldPattern[f12[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f12[2]] :> 4, HoldPattern[f12[x_]] :>  
(ToExpression["f" <> ToString[1] <> ToString[2]][x] = Evaluate[test[x]])}
```

which is not useful.

In short, I would like to see any manipulation with `test[x]` that gives me the `DownValues` to be `HoldPattern[f12[x_]] :> (ToExpression["f" <> ToString[1] <> ToString[2]][x] = x^2`. In other words, **I need `test[x]` to be evaluated first and then assigned to `{f12, f34, …}` with memoization.** On this site I think (two of) the best articles talking about memoization are [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25150/7101) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean), but I think neither solves my problem…

Comment: How about `With[{t = test[x]}, f[x_] := f[x] = t]`

Comment: @SimonWoods, it's not working: try `f[#] & /@ Range[5]` you'll get `{x^2, x^2, x^2, x^2, x^2}` instead of `{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed that. Maybe `Function` instead: `(f[x_] := f[x] = #) &[test[x]]`

Comment: @SimonWoods, this simple example works but it fails in a more complicated situation. Please see my updated text. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
ClearAll[test,"f*"];
test[i_,j_]:=
 Block[{x},
  Print@"test";
  FullSimplify[Log[Exp[x^2]],Assumptions->x>0]i+j];
indices=Partition[Range[10],2];
syms={Symbol["f"<>StringJoin[ToString/@#]],test[Sequence@@#]}&/@indices;
(#1[x_]:=#1[x]=#2)&@@@syms;
```

> test
>
> test
>
> test
>
> test
>
> test

```
f34[5]
```

> 79

```
DownValues[f34]
```

> {HoldPattern[f34[5]] :> 79, HoldPattern[f34[x_]] :> (f34[x] = 4 + 3 x^2)}

Comment: Thank you @mfvonh for your answer. Sorry for late reply -- I am on a trip and have no enough time to work things out. However I think similar answers have been provided and the main issue, as I pointed out in the updated text, is that you assign "unevaluated" `test` functions to `f`, which is not what I want.

Comment: @LeoFang Oh I see. I didn't understand that part of the issue was scoping `x`. I've taken another shot.

Comment: Thanks @mfvonh for the update! It seems to me that your answer fits all my requirements! In particular the one-line definition `(#1[x_]:=#1[x]=#2)&@@@syms;` is amazing -- is it because you collect the function names and expressions before assigning them? By the way, if you remove the line `a=x;` and change the one-line definition `(#1[x_]:=#1[x]=#2)&@@@syms;` to `(#1[a_]:=#1[a]=#2)&@@@syms;`, the whole trick is still working without using a global variable `x` (don't know why though).

Comment: Aha, `a` in `Block` is a global variable, and that's why the change I found is working.

Comment: @LeoFang `Block` is your enemy. Do not underestimate it. :)

Comment: @LeoFang I just copied that `Block` and `a=x` from somewhere but I can't remember where. I _think_ `Block[{x},...]` would work if that is all you needed. (Of course changing `a` to `x` in the expression also.)

Comment: Also, be careful with the naming of the `f`.  If you have indices {11,5} and {1,15}, for example, you will run into problems.

Comment: Also, ensure that `test` always depends on the literal `x`.  If in the `Block` you had `a=y` then `f34[5]` evaluates to `4+3y^2`.

Answer (score 2):

Will this approach work for you? If it will, then this is an answer :)

```
test[x_] := 
  Module[{a}, a = x; FullSimplify[Log[Exp[a^2]], Assumptions -> a > 0]]
Clear @ "f*"
(((ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x_] := 
     ToExpression["f" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][x] = expr;) &) /. 
       expr -> test[x]) @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
f12 /@ Range @ 4;
DownValues @ f12
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f12[1]] :> 1, 
>  HoldPattern[f12[2]] :> 4, 
>  HoldPattern[f12[3]] :> 9, 
>  HoldPattern[f12[4]] :> 16, 
>  HoldPattern[f12[x_]] :> 
>   (ToExpression["f" <> ToString[1] <> ToString[2]][x] = x^2)}
> ```

Comment: this example works but it fails when I need `test` to take the values `{{1,2}, {3,4}, …}`. Please see my updated text. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the trick is to use a `Function` approach and memoize `test` itself, as follows.
I'll use a slightly more complicated test function, and it will print EXPENSIVE! when the hard work is done:

```
 test[i_,j_] := test[i,j] = Function[x, Evaluate[Print["EXPENSIVE!"]; x^(i^j)]]
 f[i_,j_][x_]:= f[i,j][x] = test[i,j][x]

 f[1,2][x]
 (* EXPENSIVE! *)
 (*   x    *)
 f[1,2][7]
 (*   7    *)

 ?f
 (* 
      f[1,2][7]=7
      f[1,2][x]=x
      f[i_,j_][x_]:=f[i,j][x]=test[i,j][x]
 *)
 ?test
 (*
      test[1,2]=Function[x$,x$]
      test[i_,j_]:=test[i,j]=(Print[Expensive!];Function[x,Evaluate[x^i^j]])
 *)
 f[3,2][4]
 (* EXPENSIVE! *)
 (* 262144 *)
 f[3,2][3]
 (* 19683 *)
 ?f
 (*
      f[1,2][x]=x
      f[3,2][3]=19683
      f[3,2][4]=262144
      f[i_,j_][x_]:=f[i,j][x]=test[i,j][x]
 *)
 ?test
 (*
      test[1,2]=Function[x$,x$]
      test[3,2]=Function[x$,x$^9]
      test[i_,j_]:=test[i,j]=(Print[Expensive!];Function[x,Evaluate[x^i^j]])
 *)
```

Note also since f is curried (that is, the parameters are broken up into more than one set of `[brackets]`) you can do things like

```
allfuncs = f@@@ {{1,2}, {3,2}, {5,-1}}
(* {f[1,2], f[3,2], f[5,-1] *)
Through[allfuncs[2]]
(* EXPENSIVE! *)  (* just one, because test[1,2] and test[3,2] exist already... *)
(* { 2, 512, 2^(1/5) } *)
```

Also note that you can pass around the expressions `f[1,2]` before doing the corresponding hard work, since `test` only gets evaluated when `f[1,2]` is applied to some quantity.  This makes `f` somewhat lazy... only doing the hard work the first time, when it is needed.

Also note that one need not memoize `f` itself, if all of the expensive work is really being done inside `test`.

Comment: Dear @evanb, thanks for sharing this approach. The key issue in my question (and your answer) is that I need `test` to run and generate a complicated expression for subsequent calculation before it's memorized. Here you assumed that in `test` there are known expressions `Print["EXPENSIVE!"]` and `x^(i^j)`, which is not my case. For example, as you said the hard work is done only when `f[1,2]` is applied, but then every time I need `f[1,2]` for different `x` I have to generate the expression from `test` and substitute the value of `x`, which does not save time (it's not even memoization!).

Comment: Look at the first `?test`.  It has `test[1,2]=Function[x$,x$]`, meaning that the i=1 and j=2 dependence has been taken care of.  If you want `f[1,2][7]` and `f[1,2][123]` and `f[1,2][foo]`, `test` is only evaluated one time.  I thought that this is what you wanted?

Comment: Apology @evanb. I think I misunderstood your words and it seems your approach indeed gives a desired result. Let me do a larger test and see the outcome. Thank you. :)

Comment: In the meanwhile, do you have a theory to explain why it has to be a two-step approach (define `test[i,j]` and then define `f[i,j][x]`) rather than one-step (simply `Evaluate` the expression in `test` and assign to a function name)?

Comment: Well, the way I came upon this approach was to think about the different kinds of objects you wanted in your computation.  You wanted intermediate (expensive to compute) functions, and then the results of applying said functions to some quantities.  It seemed natural to break up the evaluation that way too.  There might be a one-step method to getting what you're looking for, but I bet it must be tricky...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the way you think @evanb. It's very illuminating. I've done an extensive test in my work using your approach. While it does work like a charm, as a two-step approach it has some limitation in my work due to things beyond the scope of this post. Anyway I appreciate you answer and it deserves the bounty if no other useful answer appears.

Comment: Sure!  I am curious---what is the constraint / problem?  `f[1,2]` should behave just like the symbol `f12` you originally wanted---that `test` exists at all should be totally invisible to the rest of your code.


You may find (if you memoize too many things) that your calculation slows dramatically.  This can be a result of memory constraints.  If that happens you might check out http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19536/how-to-clear-parts-of-a-memoized-function or simply not memoize `f`.

Comment: Thanks @evanb. Sorry for late reply -- I am currently on a trip and have no enough time to work things out. I thought about it and realized that the limitation probably came from some stupid function manipulations in my code. My `test` depends on some `SetDelayed` functions which is to be changed after `f` memoizes the evaluated expression. Somehow (have not figured it out yet) I made a mistake that once the `SetDelayed` functions are changed, `f` will not get the expected expressions (because it's not evaluated yet when it's defined). I'll think about it. And yes, I had the slow-down issue.

Comment: Well, one not-great workaround is to have the changed functions clear the memoized `DownValues` of f and test.  Then `test` will only be evaluated after those kinds of changes.

Comment: I really like your answer and was about to give you the bounty, but I found mfvonh's updated answer gives an amazing "one-step" approach, so I gave him the bounty at the end. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: That's fine.  It seems like his approach requires you to decide which `f` you need at the beginning, as opposed to doing all of the `test` work upon the first call of a particular `f` in my approach, so our answers certainly fulfill different niches, performance- and design-wise.  For example, if you know you need the same `f` over and over again in many different programs, doing the evaluation up front (his way) makes writing those symbols to disk simpler.

Comment: @mfvonh's solution and mine are along the same lines.  In his case, the evaluation of test is done when evaluating `syms` (and not `(#1[x_]:=#1[x]=#2)&@@@syms;`), so that we both used the "evaluate-the-i/j-dependence-first, store that answer, use that answer in another definition" method.

Answer (score 1):

I have included my own `test` function. It takes quite long to calculate and it has an unspecified variable `x`.

```
k = 4;
j = 7;
Clear@x
test[k_, j_] :=
 Simplify[Integrate[E^(k y^3 + j ) y^x Log[y], {y, k, j}]]

Clear@f
f[i_, j_, z_] :=
 (Block[{x}, 
   ReleaseHold@Hold[SetDelayed][Hold@f[i, j, x_], test[i, j]]]; 
  f[i, j, z])
```

Now, we have

```
Timing[f[1, 2, 3] // N]
```

> ```
> {6.654387,9067.81 -5.60026*10^-12 I}
> ```

This took quite long, because `test[1,2]` had to be calculated. But if we use the same `i` and `j` now, things are faster

```
Timing[f[1, 2, 4] // N]
```

> ```
> {0.005643,17423.1 -1.12005*10^-12 I}
> ```

**About the code**

The idea is similar to that in usual memoization. `f[1,2,x_]` is a more specific pattern than `f[i_,j_,z_]`, so the newer definition will be prioritised. This  technique using `ReleaseHold` and wrapping a head in `Hold` seems to be something only I use. To get an basic idea of what is going on, imagine `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` are not there, they only change the order of evaluation.

A more detailed explanation is as follows. I try to avoid having `SetDelayed` as a head of an expression on the RHS of another `SetDelayed`, or inside `Block`. Unexpected things can happen if we nest scoping constructs like this. So alternatively we could have written the following, in which the order of evaluation is the same.

```
Clear@g
g[i_, j_, z_] :=
 (Block[{x}, g[i, j, x_] := Evaluate@test[i, j]]; 
  g[i, j, z])
```

But then after evaluating `g[1,2,3]`, we have a definition like this

```
g[1, 2, x$_] := ...
```

Where we have `x$` instead of `x`, which makes the code fail.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob Akkerboom for your answer. Sorry for late reply -- I am on a trip and have no enough time to work things out. Your answer looks interesting and seems to be working. I'll think about it when my trip is over.

Comment: @LeoFang ok, no worries, enjoy your trip :). By the way I also like the answer by evanb, just an alternative here.

Comment: Thanks. I like evanb's answer too. The `ReleaseHold`/`Hold` business is always a mystery to me :P