# What are the applications of using functions whose heads are also functions?

Tags: function-construction

I noticed that it is possible to construct something like `f[x][y]`.  Displaying this in `TreeForm` indicates that this expression has head `f[x]`; and it seems to imply that this is really a function of `y`, and the name of this function is *another function* `f[x]`!

So what are the uses of such constructs?  Could `x` for example be like an index that labels a family functions?

Comment: [wikipedia>> Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

Comment: E.g. `SortBy[Last]`, indexed variables `x[1][t]`, `x[2][t]` in a DE system,....I just used `Through[OptionValue["EventFunctions"][ics]]` in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves/64923#64923).

Comment: In V10 new operator forms have been introduced. One can use `SubValues` to get similar functionality. It can be quite useful.

Comment: I often use it when I want to reuse expensive results.  For example, [in this case of function memoization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48137/how-to-do-memoization-together-with-evaluation-of-a-complicated-function/48288#48288), or when I want to fix some of a function's parameters and Map over another set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about this syntax is in terms of "functions with parameters that accept inputs".  The normal way this is written is

```
function[inputs..., parameters...]
```

this structure leads to a somewhat awkward syntax when mapping over a list of inputs:

```
list = {1.234, 5.678};
(Round[#1, 0.1] & ) /@ list

(* {1.2, 5.7} *)
```

The two-argument-list syntax allows you to construct a parameterized operator that acts upon inputs:

```
round[a_][x_] := Round[x, a];
round[0.1] /@ list

(* {1.2, 5.7} *)
```

which is a little tidier.  I believe the explosion of built-in functions which permit this syntax is due to the new `Query` function in version 10:

```
Query[round[0.1]][list]

(* {1.2, 5.7} *)
```

In general, there is a lot more support for more formal functional programming style in version 10.