# How can I partially evaluate a function?

Tags: functions, evaluation

I have a multivariable function, from which I'd like to define a marginalization:

f(a,b,c,d,...,z) ---> g(a,1,c,d,...,z)

Generally, g will have fewer argument than f, possibly none (full evaluation). Is it possible to take the output of a function and transform it into a second function?

This is part of a looped Block[] segment in a larger code, where the number of variables, slot positions, and their values are specified anew on each iteration.

Here is my best failed attempt:

```
PartialEvaluate[func_, totargs_, args_, targets_] :=

Block[{tmp, g, r},

tmp = Table[Slot[i], {i, 1, totargs}];

Do[tmp[[targets[[slot]]]] = args[[slot]];, {slot, 1, Length[targets]}];

g = Function[func @@ tmp]

Return[g];
];
```

Thanks

Comment: `g[a_,c_]:= f[a, 1, c]`?

Comment: How are the variables specified?

Comment: I've updated the post with an example.

Comment: You mean partial application?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48137/7936

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated version**

To be more in line with what the OP wanted, we have the following updated code. Given inputs (in order) `g`, `totargs = 5`, `args = {x[1],x[4]}`, and `targets = {1,4}`, if we call the function

```
partialEvaluate[func_, totargs_, args_, targets_] := Block[{argsEvaluated = 1, newArgs = 1}
 , Evaluate[func @@ Table[
    If[MemberQ[targets, i], args[[argsEvaluated++]], Slot[newArgs++]]
    , {i, 1, totargs}]
   ] &
]
```

the result is

```
g[x[1], #1, #2, x[4], #3] &
```

The main reason the OP's original code didn't work is that `Function` has the `Attribute` `HoldAll`:

```
Attributes[Function]
(* {HoldAll, Protected} *)
```

If you want the insides of `Function` to be evaluated, you have to explicitly `Evaluate` it, as I've done.

**Original post**

I'm not sure of exactly what the inputs and outputs should be, but here's my best guess as to what you want, with minimal changes to your code. For the purpose of concreteness, let's suppose that `totargs = 5`, `args = {x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5]}`, and the target variables to which the function is going to be applied to are `targets = {1,4}`. Then if we call the function

```
partialEvaluate[func_, totargs_, args_, targets_] := Block[{tmp}
  , tmp = Table[Slot[i], {i, 1, totargs}]
  ; tmp[[targets]] = args[[targets]]
  ; Evaluate[func @@ tmp] &
]
```

with the input

```
partialEvaluate[g, 5, {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]}, {1, 4}]
```

we get the pure function

```
g[x[1], #2, #3, x[4], #5] &
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the accept! However, are you sure? Is it possible that what you actually want is `g[x[1], #1, #2, x[4], #3] &`? Because I imagine you will want to apply this new function to a three-element list, rather than still a five element list. If so, I can update with a new version that returns this alternative version

Comment: Ah, I forgot to share. I added a simple `j=1;Do[If[tmp[[i]]==Slot[i],tmp[[i]]=Slot[j++],{i,Range[totargs]}]` fix. before the evaluation step. Share your solution anyway, it's probably more clever!

Comment: That's essentially what I did, actually, but I'll post anyway, since it's slightly cleaner.

Comment: A pedantic difference, but my ugly do loop was to account for a `Length[args]=Length[targets]` constraint which I didn't mention earlier.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @sampson I see. I think I have a version that works for exactly what you want, now. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Since mathematica does not use currying evaluation like language like haskell, you should do the currying for partial evaluation by yourself.

Here is some simple example:

```
In[1]:= addx[x_] := Function[y, x + y]
In[2]:= addx[3][4]
Out[2]:= 7
In[3]:= add3 = addx[3]
Out[3]:= Function[y$, 3 + y$]
In[4]:= add3[4]
Out[4]:= 7
```

In general, you should make the function you want to partial evaluate take arguments and return **another function** which take the remaining arguments. And then you can pass few arguments to the function and you will get another function which can be applied to the remaining arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, didn't know about 'currying'. Unfortunately the structure of func is fixed by other elements of the larger code. I was hoping to find a solution to the problem as I posted it above. it is sufficiently general and presumably will be simple to solve. but I'm not sure why the application of the Function fails to recruit the slots in the output of Apply [func].

Answer (score 1):

March's version is problematic: in case the original function uses itself pure functions in its definition then this can lead to unintended results and errors. Consider the following example:

```
foo[x_,y_] := (x #)& /@ {x,y}
```

Partial evaluation of foo with the second argument set to three should result in a function that is equivalent to:

```
fooPartial[x_] := (x #)& /@ {x,3}
```

If we now use march's method for partial evaluation we get the following pure function

```
{#1^2, 9}&
```

which is equivalent to

```
fooPartialWrong[x_] := (# #)& /@ {x,3}
```

which is **not** equivalent to `fooPartial`! The problem is that the `#`'s in the argument of foo and in the definition get mixed up.

A further problem (probably even more problematic in this case) is that `Evaluate` "breaks" scoping

```
In[1]:= x = 3                                                                   

Out[1]= 3

In[2]:= foo2[x_,y_]:= Evaluate[x y]                                              

In[3]:= ?foo2                                                                    
Global`foo2

foo2[x_, y_] := 3*y
```

A better method is to exploit the fact that `List` does not have the attribute `HoldAll` (see [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766)):

```
Module[{x},SetDelayed @@ {fooPartial[x_],foo[x,3]}]
```

In rewriting `partialEvaluate` one cannot use `Module` as above since the number of variables scoped by `Module` is fixed, so I use `Unique` instead to avoid side-effects.

```
partialEvaluate2[func_, funcPartial_, totargs_, args_, targets_] :=
 Module[{num1 = 1,num2 = 1,variablesNames,variablesNamesUnderscore},
  variablesNames = Unique /@ ConstantArray["x",totargs - Length[args]];
  variablesNamesUnderscore = Pattern[#,Blank[]]& /@ variablesNames;
  SetDelayed @@ {funcPartial@@variablesNamesUnderscore, func @@ Table[
    If[MemberQ[targets, i], args[[num1++]], variablesNames[[num2++]]],
    {i, 1, totargs}]}
 ]
```

And we now get as desired:

```
In[1]:= partialEvaluate2[foo,fooPartial,2,{3},{2}] 
In[2]:= ?fooPartial                                                                                                                           
Global`fooPartial                                                                                                                              

fooPartial[x31_] := {x31^2, 3*x31}
```