# Tree-like data sets with efficient storage and retrieval

Tags: recursion, data-structures

Most probably this is going to be a duplicate, sorry. I found too many questions/answers here about tree-like structures, and still could not locate what I want.

It is a followup of my previous question [Clever caching of a recursively defined function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182268/35000); I've implemented that according to the very nice answer, but it sort of reached its limit, so now I want something more quick and memory efficient.

I need to compute lots of (integer) values of the form `f[n,{a1,...,ak}]` which depend on each other in a certain way, so I want to store the intermediate results. Seemingly an optimal way to do it would be a list `{F[1],...,F[M]}` where each `F[n]` is a tree-like structure, with `F[n][a1]` holding the value of `f[n,{a1}]`, together with all `F[n][a1][a2]` for which `f[n,{a1,a2,...}]` have been computed, etc. There are several ways to do it that would be very fast at retrieval, but I am not sure how to achieve memory efficiency. I should use some nested `Association` or `Dataset` or what?

To be specific, here is what I actually want to compute:

```
stepreduce[{n_, a_, b_}] :=
 Which[
  b == {} \[Or] n == -1, {n, a, b},
  a == {} \[Or] First[a] < First[b], {n, b, a},
  First[a] == First[b], {If[n == 1, 0, -1], {}, {}},
  True, With[{d = First[a] - First[b], 
    r = Mod[First[b], First[a] - First[b]]},
   {n - First[b], Join[If[r == 0, {d}, {d - r, r}], Rest[a]], Rest[b]}
   ]
  ]

reduce[n_, a_, k_] := Most[FixedPoint[stepreduce, {n, a, {k}}]]

compute[n_, a_] := 
 If[n < 0, 0, 
  If[a == {}, If[n == 0, 1, Sum[compute[n, {k}], {k, n}]], 
   Sum[compute @@ reduce[n, a, k], {k, n}]]]

f[n_] := compute[n, {}]
```

Thus for example `f[3]` requires `compute[3,{1}]`, `compute[3,{2}]` and `compute[3,{3}]`, while `compute[3,{1}]` and `compute[3,{3}]` require `compute[2,{1,1}]`, etc.

Comment: I'm not positive but suspect a nested `Association` would be a good way to proceed. Alternatively you might just set down values as you proceed e.g. `compute[3,{1}]=intermediate` allows you to have later access to `compute[3,{1}]` without needing to recompute it.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau With the second alternative, there would be lots of redundant stuff in memory - e. g. keeping separately `compute[n,{a,b,c,...,k,1}]=x1`, `compute[n,{a,b,c,...,k,2}]=x2`,...,`compute[n,{a,b,c,...,k,j}]=xj` while I could have them gathered in something like `F[[n]][a][b][c]...[k]=<|1->x1,2->x2,...,j->xj|>`, this kind of thing...

Comment: Roughly speaking, I would like to have each `F[[n]]` a rooted tree-like structure, with directed paths along `(root)->a->b->c->...->k` for all stored `compute[n,{a,b,c,...,k}]` ending in leaves holding the values of the latter. Of course this makes sense only if one can build such kind of structure economically memorywise

Comment: How large are `n`s that you're interested in, and how much memory you have available?

Comment: @jkuczm Previously I managed to reach `n=107` at a computer with 320 gb ram, but with a very primitive code - just kept in memory everything that was going on. Right now I only have 8 unfortunately but if I manage to optimize it well enough I can ask access there again - hoping to get to `n=200`. Mostly at this stage I need to study statistics/dynamics of function calls, so I can keep in memory only the part without which computations will go too slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Simple memoization

There are few places where we can optimize code from OP.

Let's start with already mentioned in OP simplest memoization.

```
stepreduce // ClearAll
stepreduce@{n_, a_, b_} := Which[
  b == {} \[Or] n == -1,
    {n, a, b},
  a == {} \[Or] First@a < First@b,
    {n, b, a},
  First@a == First@b,
    {If[n == 1, 0, -1], {}, {}},
  True,
    With[{d = First@a - First@b, r = Mod[First@b, First@a - First@b]},
      {n - First@b, Join[If[r == 0, {d}, {d - r, r}], Rest@a], Rest@b}
    ]
]

reduce // ClearAll
reduce[n_, a_, k_] := Most@FixedPoint[stepreduce, {n, a, {k}}]

compute // ClearAll
compute[-1, {}] = 0;
compute[0, {}] = 1;
compute[n_, {}] := compute[n, {}] = Sum[compute[n, {k}], {k, n}]
compute[n_, a_] := compute[n, a] = Sum[compute @@ reduce[n, a, k], {k, n}]

f // ClearAll
f@n_ := compute[n, {}]
```

Let's gather time and memory usage of above function for calculating first 40 values.

```
results = <||>;

AppendTo[results, "DownValues memoization" -> Table[
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{compute}, Module[{res},
    Prepend[AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[res = f@i], res]
  ]],
  {i, 40}
]] // Last
(* {{1, 0.000074, 3984}, {2, 0.000121, 4208}, {6, 0.000284, 5136}, {14, 0.000663, 6680},
    {34, 0.001389, 8592}, {68, 0.003436, 11312}, {150, 0.010413, 15192}, {296, 0.014905, 21256},
    {586, 0.017695, 30344}, {1140, 0.025606, 44104}, {2182, 0.051756, 68168}, {4130, 0.072319, 93312},
    {7678, 0.121303, 136872}, {14368, 0.179369, 208728}, {26068, 0.286492, 297072}, {48248, 0.449439, 418840},
    {86572, 0.731423, 627224}, {158146, 1.17463, 878960}, {281410, 1.77709, 1298176}, {509442, 2.57542, 1811608},
    {901014, 4.01303, 2669760}, {1618544, 6.20318, 3717656}, {2852464, 9.20258, 5471776}, {5089580, 13.7751, 7606608},
    {8948694, 21.0816, 11174504}, {15884762, 31.8216, 15514256}, {27882762, 48.4341, 22760552}, {49291952, 71.3518, 31979744},
    {86435358, 108.607, 46273240}, {152316976, 159.118, 64178184}, {266907560, 229.416, 93926304}, {469232204, 337.286, 130198288},
    {821844316, 505.145, 190618272}, {1442300988, 745.747, 264372384}, {2525295380, 1108., 386819480}, {4426185044, 1607.57, 536494800},
    {7747801190, 2397.82, 784631984}, {13567867834, 3492.71, 1088333528}, {23745303556, 5196.81, 1591114776}, {41557384062, 7588.04, 2210837400}} *)
```

---

## `reduce` compilation

Further speed-up can be gained by compiling `reduce` function.

We can see that, inside `stepreduce`, whenever `a` list can increase it's length, `b` list decreases it's length. Total length of `a` and `b` lists can't grow during `reduce` call. So we can start with single list $\{n, \, a_m, \, a_{m-1}, \, \ldots, \, a_1, \, b_1 = k\}$, keep track of length and positions of first elements of `a` and `b` lists, and of "direction" in which possible change in positions of first elements will move. This way we can perform all steps of `reduce` without memory reallocation.

Since compiled function can't return ragged arrays, we'll move around single list `na` containing `n` as first element and reversed `a` list as rest of elements.

```
reduce // ClearAll
reduce = Hold@Compile[{{na, _Integer, 1}, {k, _Integer}},
  Module[{n, aPos, aLen, bPos, bLen, posDelta, nab},
    n = na[[1]];
    aPos = Length@na;
    aLen = aPos - 1;
    bLen = 1;
    bPos = aPos + 1;
    posDelta = 1;
    nab = Append[na, k];
    While[True,
      Which[
        bLen < 1 || n === -1,
          Break[],
        aLen < 1  || nab[[aPos]] < nab[[bPos]],
          With[{aLenOld = aLen, aPosOld = aPos},
            aLen = bLen;
            bLen = aLenOld;
            aPos = bPos;
            bPos = aPosOld;
            posDelta = -posDelta;
          ],
        nab[[aPos]] === nab[[bPos]],
          n = If[n === 1, 0, -1];
          aLen = 0;
          Break[],
        True,
          Module[{bFirst, d, r},
            bFirst = nab[[bPos]];
            d = nab[[aPos]] - bFirst;
            r = Mod[bFirst, d];
            n = n - bFirst;
            If[r === 0,
              nab[[aPos]] = d;
            (* else *),
              nab[[aPos]] = r;
              aPos += posDelta;
              nab[[aPos]] = d - r;
              ++aLen;
            ];
            bPos += posDelta;
            --bLen;
          ]
      ];
    ];
    If[posDelta === -1,
      Module[{max, reverseMax},
        max = Length@nab + 2;
        reverseMax = Quotient[max - 1, 2];
        If[aLen + 1 < reverseMax, reverseMax = aLen + 1];
        Do[
          With[{tmp = nab[[i]], j = max - i},
            nab[[i]] = nab[[j]];
            nab[[j]] = tmp;
          ];,
          {i, 2, reverseMax}
        ]
      ]
    ];
    nab[[1]] = n;
    Take[nab, aLen + 1]
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
] /.
  Part -> Compile`GetElement //. HoldPattern[Compile`GetElement@x__ = y_] :> (Part@x = y) //.
  HoldPattern[Plus][pre___, x_, HoldPattern[Times][-1, y_], post___] :> Plus[pre, Subtract[x, y], post] //
  ReleaseHold // Last;

compute // ClearAll
compute@{-1} = 0;
compute@{0} = 1;
compute@na_ := compute@na = With[{n = First@na},
  If[Length@na === 1,
    Sum[compute@{n, k}, {k, n}]
  (* else *),
    Sum[compute@Developer`FromPackedArray@reduce[na, k], {k, n}]
  ]
]

f // ClearAll
f@n_ := compute@{n}
```

Again time and memory usage:

```
AppendTo[results, "DownValues memoization + compilation" -> Table[
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{compute}, Module[{res},
    Prepend[AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[res = f@i], res]
  ]],
  {i, 40}
]] // Last
(* {{1, 0.000063, 2832}, {2, 0.000078, 4136}, {6, 0.000091, 5424}, {14, 0.00017, 6720},
    {34, 0.000332, 9376}, {68, 0.000605, 11616}, {150, 0.001157, 15024}, {296, 0.001871, 21344},
    {586, 0.003039, 29936}, {1140, 0.005082, 43944}, {2182, 0.007769, 62952}, {4130, 0.011655, 92952},
    {7678, 0.014263, 136368}, {14368, 0.023007, 195168}, {26068, 0.033489, 287104}, {48248, 0.050387, 408872},
    {86572, 0.075441, 598824}, {158146, 0.101385, 850560}, {281410, 0.140992, 1241104}, {509442, 0.211831, 1820328},
    {901014, 0.32101, 2612696}, {1618544, 0.460999, 3660608}, {2852464, 0.680271, 5414824}, {5089580, 1.19728, 7549832},
    {8948694, 1.50457, 11118344}, {15884762, 2.29116, 15459152}, {27882762, 3.47475, 22708256}, {49291952, 4.49639, 31527560},
    {86435358, 6.61805, 46235728}, {152316976, 9.90871, 64156608}, {266907560, 14.3602, 93992544}, {469232204, 19.7709, 130377928},
    {821844316, 29.5902, 190884312}, {1442300988, 42.7437, 264764776}, {2525295380, 62.8208, 387425584}, {4426185044, 92.3726, 537406200},
    {7747801190, 130.204, 786031768}, {13567867834, 183.552, 1090416752}, {23745303556, 267.809, 1594242360}, {41557384062, 391.204, 2211848640}} *)
```

---

## Caching in a tree

As noted by OP different `a` lists share many elements, so it might be more memory efficient to store result in a specially constructed tree.

While `Association`s offer fast appending and random access they're also pretty memory hungry, so might not be the best choice for this memory constrained problem.

Instead I propose to use the fact that "ordinary" compound *Mathematica* expression is a tree, so we can keep results in an expression such that our `na` list will be position of either result, or of sub-expression having result as it's head.

Such expression offers fast random access, but appending to a node of $k$ elements is $\mathcal O(k)$ operation. Since nodes won't have more than `n` elements, this shouldn't have huge performance impact.

```
integerTreeResizeStep = Function[,
  With[{node = #1},
    Which[
      IntegerQ@node,
        #1 = Array[-1&, #2, 1, node],
      Length@node < #2,
        #1 = Join[node, Array[-1&, #2 - Length@node, 1, Head@node]]
    ];
  ];
  Unevaluated@Unevaluated@#1[[#2]]
  ,
  HoldFirst
];
integerTreeGetOrSetLeaf = Function[{tree, path, value},
  Module[{val},
    val = Quiet@Check[
      Extract[tree, path]
      ,
      Fold[integerTreeResizeStep, Unevaluated@tree, path];
      -1
    ];
    If[Not@IntegerQ@val, val = Head@val];
    If[val < 0,
      val = value;
      If[IntegerQ@Extract[tree, path],
        tree[[Sequence @@ path]] = val
      (* else *),
        tree[[Sequence @@ path, 0]] = val
      ];
    ];
    val
  ],
  HoldAll
];

$cache = {};

compute // ClearAll
compute@{-1} = 0;
compute@{0} = 1;
compute@na_ := integerTreeGetOrSetLeaf[$cache, na,
  With[{n = First@na},
    If[Length@na === 1,
      Sum[compute@{n, k}, {k, n}]
    (* else *),
      Sum[compute@reduce[na, k], {k, n}]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Time and memory usage:

```
AppendTo[results, "Tree cache + compilation" -> Table[
  Module[{res},
    $cache = {};
    Prepend[AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[res = f@i], res]
  ],
  {i, 40}
]] // Last
(* {{1, 0.000261, 10176}, {2, 0.000286, 14008}, {6, 0.000478, 17800}, {14, 0.000841, 21712},
    {34, 0.001428, 25624}, {68, 0.002476, 29536}, {150, 0.003977, 33448}, {296, 0.006287, 37360},
    {586, 0.00936, 41272}, {1140, 0.014786, 45184}, {2182, 0.022635, 49096}, {4130, 0.034472, 53016},
    {7678, 0.051892, 56920}, {14368, 0.078604, 60840}, {26068, 0.118647, 64744}, {48248, 0.177518, 68664},
    {86572, 0.25746, 81520}, {158146, 0.381425, 98904}, {281410, 0.558052, 131784}, {509442, 0.816168, 167584},
    {901014, 1.19629, 232680}, {1618544, 1.73458, 305024}, {2852464, 2.53002,  434480}, {5089580, 3.64807, 580352},
    {8948694, 5.27007, 838488}, {15884762, 7.58268, 1130824}, {27882762, 10.9998, 1646504}, {49291952, 15.8523, 2231320},
    {86435358, 23.3352, 3261424}, {152316976, 33.9201, 4431688}, {266907560, 47.8143, 6489776}, {469232204, 69.2132, 8828752},
    {821844316, 99.1624, 12943664}, {1442300988, 143.114, 17620240}, {2525295380, 207.741, 25844920}, {4426185044, 293.7, 35193936},
    {7747801190, 432.95, 51638240}, {13567867834, 618.074, 70324968}, {23745303556, 887.757, 103203720}, {41557384062, 1258.96, 140563328}} *)
```

---

## Sharing nodes

If we examine our `$cache` we'll see that there's large percentage of nodes containing only zeros. Especially common are nodes that can be created by prepending flat zero node to itself.

```
Table[Count[$cache, Nest[Prepend[#, #] &, 0 @@ ConstantArray[0, j], i - 1], Infinity], {i, 20}, {j, 40 - 2 i}] // TableForm
Total[%, 2]
(* 2041389 *)
```

We can reduce memory usage by making sure that, in our cache tree, same zero nodes are internally stored as pointers to single expressions, not as copies of this expression.

We can do this by keeping zero node expressions cached, e.g. as down values of `zeroNode` symbol. When zero is added to cache tree, we can test whether containing it node is of our special form, if so we can replace it with cached version.

```
zeroNode // ClearAll
zeroNode[1, _] = 0;
zeroNode[2, i_] := zeroNode[2, i] = 0 @@ ConstantArray[0, i];
zeroNode[depth_, i_] := zeroNode[depth, i] = Prepend[zeroNode[depth - 1, i], zeroNode[depth - 1, i]]

integerTreeOptimizeZeroNode = Function[{tree, path},
  Module[{newPath = Most@path, node, cached},
    node = Extract[tree, newPath];
    cached = zeroNode[Depth@node, Count[node, 0]];
    While[node === cached,
      tree[[Sequence @@ newPath]] = cached;
      newPath = Most@newPath;
      node = Extract[tree, newPath];
      cached = zeroNode[Depth@node, Count[node, 0]]
    ];
  ]
  ,
  HoldFirst
];
integerTreeGetOrSetLeaf = Function[{tree, path, value},
  Module[{val},
    val = Quiet@Check[
      Extract[tree, path]
      ,
      Fold[integerTreeResizeStep, Unevaluated@tree, path];
      -1
    ];
    If[Not@IntegerQ@val, val = Head@val];
    If[val < 0,
      val = value;
      If[IntegerQ@Extract[tree, path],
        tree[[Sequence @@ path]] = val
      (* else *),
        tree[[Sequence @@ path, 0]] = val
      ];
      If[val === 0, integerTreeOptimizeZeroNode[tree, path]]
    ];
    val
  ],
  HoldAll
];
```

Time and memory usage:

```
AppendTo[results, "Tree cache + compilation + shared nodes" -> Table[
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{zeroNode}, Module[{res},
    $cache = {};
    Prepend[AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[res = f@i], res]
  ]],
  {i, 40}
]] // Last
(* {{1, 0.000206, 10736}, {2, 0.000256, 14848}, {6, 0.000448, 18920}, {14, 0.000858, 23112},
    {34, 0.001798, 27304}, {68, 0.003416, 31496}, {150, 0.007841, 35688}, {296, 0.014545, 39880},
    {586, 0.019235, 44072}, {1140, 0.017669, 48264}, {2182, 0.029496, 52456}, {4130, 0.042167, 56656},
    {7678, 0.064716, 60840}, {14368, 0.098059, 65040}, {26068, 0.137533, 69224}, {48248, 0.198948, 73424},
    {86572, 0.297026, 77608}, {158146, 0.440113, 86200}, {281410, 0.645397, 97752}, {509442, 0.945092, 115080},
    {901014, 1.39239, 128512}, {1618544, 2.01232, 159560}, {2852464, 3.04968, 180984}, {5089580, 4.37024, 237376},
    {8948694, 6.2295, 263520}, {15884762, 8.86484, 367256}, {27882762, 12.9779, 413672}, {49291952, 18.4895, 610232},
    {86435358, 27.0952, 674016}, {152316976, 39.3753, 1047472}, {266907560, 57.412, 1176016}, {469232204, 81.8548, 1901088},
    {821844316, 119.4, 2092472}, {1442300988, 170.801, 3499760}, {2525295380, 246.583, 3889176}, {4426185044, 355.022, 6659784},
    {7747801190, 516.578, 7312040}, {13567867834, 731.325, 12764352}, {23745303556, 1059.77, 14108216}, {41557384062, 1592.29, 24914200}} *)
```

---

## Iterative version

Let's gather data on `a` lists used after calculating `f@n`'s for subsequent `n`s from `1` to `nMax`.

```
$cache = {};
$cacheHistory = Table[f@n; $cache, {n, 40}];
```

Set of `a` lists can be generated from cache element by taking `Position`s and deleting trailing zeros, for example 4th cache element after calculating `f@n`'s up to `7` contains values calculated for following `a` lists:

```
Sort[Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros /@ Position[$cacheHistory[[7, 4]], _Integer]]
(* {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1},
    {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}} *)
```

In `a` lists we get from `$cacheHistory` we can notice that, for given `nMax` and `n`, last elements of `a` lists are all integers from `1` to `n`, and remaining elements form all compositions of all numbers from `0` to `Min[n - last, nMax - n]`.

Let's check this for all calculated `$cacheHistory` elements, i.e. up to `40`:

```
And @@ Flatten@Table[
  SameQ[
    Sort[Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros /@ Position[$cacheHistory[[nMax, n]], _Integer]],
    Table[
      Append@last /@ Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions@totMost,
      {last, n},
      {totMost, 0, Min[n - last, nMax - n]}
    ] // Flatten[#, 2]& // Prepend@{} // Sort
  ],
  {nMax, 40},
  {n, nMax}
]
(* True *)
```

Proving whether above observation is true for arbitrary large `n`s is left as an exercise for the reader.

Assuming that it is true, we can replace our recursive function with explicit iteration in which we can sequentially pre-compute all necessary cache elements for given `n`.

In recursive version absence of element in cache meant that it was not yet calculated and needs to be calculated when requested.
In iterative version we know (given our above assumption) that when cache element is requested it was already calculated, so we can use absence of element in cache as sign that its calculation resulted in some chosen default cache value.
This way, by not storing this default value in our cache (except when it's needed to fill space up to last non-default value in a node), we can reduce cache size.

Most common value in cache is zero, so we choose it as our default.

```
nextNA = Hold@Compile[{{prev, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{prevLen, nextLen, next},
    prevLen = Length@prev;
    nextLen = prevLen + prev[[prevLen - 1]] - 2;
    next = Table[1, nextLen];
    Do[next[[i]] = prev[[i]];, {i, prevLen - 3}];
    next[[prevLen - 2]] = prev[[prevLen - 2]] + 1;
    If[nextLen >= prevLen, next[[prevLen - 1]] = 1];
    next
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
] /.
  Part -> Compile`GetElement //. HoldPattern[Compile`GetElement@x__ = y_] :> (Part@x = y) //.
  HoldPattern[Plus][pre___, x_, HoldPattern[Times][-1, y_], post___] :> Plus[pre, Subtract[x, y], post] //
  ReleaseHold // Last;

$cache = {};

cacheResizeStep = Function[,
  With[{node = #1},
    Which[
      IntegerQ@node,
        #1 = Array[0&, #2, 1, node],
      Length@node < #2,
        #1 = Join[node, Array[0&, #2 - Length@node, 1, Head@node]]
    ];
  ];
  Unevaluated@Unevaluated@#1[[#2]]
  ,
  HoldFirst
];

cacheGet // ClearAll
cacheGet@{-1} = 0;
cacheGet@{0} = 1;
cacheGet@na_ := Quiet@Check[Replace[Extract[$cache, na], node: Except@_Integer :> Head@node], 0]

cacheSet = With[{val = Sum[cacheGet@reduce[#, k], {k, First@#}]},
  If[val =!= 0,
    Fold[cacheResizeStep, Unevaluated@$cache, #];
    $cache[[Sequence @@ #]] = val
  ]
]&;

preCompute = With[{oldN = Length@$cache},
  Do[
    If[nn > oldN, Do[cacheSet@{nn, last}, {last, nn}]];
    Do[
      Module[{na = ConstantArray[1, tot + 2]},
        na[[1]] = nn;
        Do[
          Do[
            na[[-1]] = last;
            cacheSet@na
            ,
            {last, nn - tot}
          ];
          na = nextNA@na;
          ,
          2^(tot - 1)
        ]
      ],
      {tot, Max[oldN - nn + 1, 1], Min[nn, # - nn]}
    ];
    If[nn > oldN, $cache[[nn, 0]] = Sum[cacheGet@{nn, k}, {k, nn}]]
    ,
    {nn, Ceiling[oldN, 2] / 2 + 1, #}
  ]
]&;

f // ClearAll
f@n_ := (preCompute@n; $cache[[n, 0]])
```

Time and memory usage:

```
AppendTo[results, "Tree cache + compilation + iterative" -> Table[
  Module[{res},
    $cache = {};
    Prepend[AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[res = f@i], res]
  ],
  {i, 40}
]] // Last
(* {{1, 0.000238, 5152}, {2, 0.000694, 5264}, {6, 0.00071, 6768}, {14, 0.001154, 6888},
    {34, 0.002287, 7136}, {68, 0.003436, 7424}, {150, 0.006044, 7808}, {296, 0.009524, 8304},
    {586, 0.014249, 8896}, {1140, 0.021613, 9792}, {2182, 0.029021, 10848}, {4130, 0.045345, 12544},
    {7678, 0.051793, 14144}, {14368, 0.055507, 17112}, {26068, 0.08087, 20016}, {48248, 0.106901, 25048},
    {86572, 0.146255, 29152}, {158146, 0.216362, 37416}, {281410, 0.320636, 44344}, {509442, 0.479902, 58144},
    {901014, 0.601251, 68120}, {1618544, 0.849296, 91216}, {2852464, 1.21726, 108184}, {5089580, 1.72727, 145896},
    {8948694, 2.46205, 169600}, {15884762, 3.51142, 228200}, {27882762, 5.0261, 267120}, {49291952, 7.33004, 361400},
    {86435358, 10.3712, 416728}, {152316976, 14.6958, 567296}, {266907560, 21.4333, 658512}, {469232204, 32.6764, 890880},
    {821844316, 44.3283, 1017496}, {1442300988, 62.5927, 1376632}, {2525295380, 89.3019, 1578752}, {4426185044, 127.182, 2138352},
    {7747801190, 183.395, 2425000}, {13567867834, 261.899, 3297264}, {23745303556, 378.116, 3757568}, {41557384062, 533.63, 5084384}} *)
```

---

## Comparisons

Let's check that all methods gave same results

```
SameQ @@ results[[All, All, 1]]
(* True *)
```

and compare their time and memory usage

```
ReplacePart[First@#, 1 -> GraphicsGrid[List /@ #[[All, 1]]]] &@(
  ListLogPlot[results[[All, All, First@#]], AxesLabel -> Last@#] & /@
    {2 -> "Time [s]", 3 -> "Memory [B]"}
)
```

[image: time and memory usage comparison]

We can see that simplest `DownValues` memoization has highest memory usage, regardless of compilation. `DownValues` memoization with compilation is fastest as long as we have enough memory. Iterative tree cache has lowest memory usage and, with compiled reduce, is only slightly slower than fastest variant.

Further optimizations might require rewriting in lower level language. But since this algorithm is not using any sophisticated high level *Mathematica* functionality, it should be doable.

Comment: Very nice work (and I got to be the first to upvote-- hope there are more to follow).

Comment: Well I am overwhelmed. What can I say? Thank you, thank you! Thank you for sharing so much of your time, effort, and expertise. There were several cases when I received much help from the SE network but this is something truly exceptional. I'll never forget this, and I'll be never able to thank you appropriately. The word that comes to mind is grace...

Comment: Reached `i=46` with the last version in less than 4 hours! One question: why do you clear `$cache` for each `i` inside the cycle? Without it, for e. g. `i=40` I had `{41557384062, 486.9017940141061, 22046688}` (you show `{41557384062, 1460.39, 48706960}`)

Comment: One more question - your zero nodes confuse me. Say, `$cache[[7]]//TreeForm` shows lots of zero-only branches. Should they be there? I thought what you do is that since everything below a zero in the (downwards growing) tree consists of zeroes only, you (1) moving down along some `path`, as soon as you encounter zero you return it without moving any further; (2) you don't keep track of anything below a zero. But you seem to do something different. What is it? And why?

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. When monitoring, I see that after a while `ByteCount[$cache]` begins to exceed `MemoryInUse[]`. How can this be??

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე "why do you clear $cache for each i inside the cycle?". It's just for the benchmark. I wanted to show how much time and memory it takes to get particular `n` from scratch.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე "Sharing nodes" doesn't change anything in top level appearance of expression, it changes their internal representation only. Non-atomic *Mathematica* expression is roughly speaking an array of pointers to its parts. If parts happen to be identical then, depending on how expression is created, those pointers can point to sub-expressions stored separately in memory, or to single sub-expressions stored only once in memory. So in this implementation there is no short-circuiting on accessing zeros, everything inside zero node is tracked, ...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე ... it's just tracked in more memory efficient way than in non-sharing version. `ByteCount` is also "fooled" by this trick, in details section of [`ByteCount` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html) we find: "ByteCount does not take account of any sharing of subexpressions. The results it gives assume that every part of the expression is stored separately. ByteCount will therefore often give an overestimate of the amount of memory currently needed to store a particular expression."

Comment: I see. Thank you for the thorough answer. So when `//TreeForm` reveals subtrees with lots of zeros this is just unraveling of loops (self-pointing nodes)? But still, when in `integerTreeGetOrSetLeaf` you do `Extract[tree, path]`, don't you traverse this loop the number of times equal to the length of the path? Once zero is encountered you could just stop and return zero, no?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე `TreeForm` or any other form of viewing the expression, even simple evaluation of `$cache[[7]]` just follows internally stored pointers. In `$cache[[7]]`, for example, we can see 8 `0[0[0], 0]` subexpressions, but internally, with node sharing, actual `0[0[0], 0]` expression is stored only once in memory and in `$cache[[7]]` there are 8 pointers to it. Yes `Extract[tree, path]` is following these internal pointers and yes this means it needs to do it as many times as there are elements in path. ...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე ... But this is the most basic built-in operation, so I'm sure it's optimized to death on lowest possible level. Short-circuiting on zero nodes would have to be implemented as a top level loop, which for relatively shallow tree, with at most 200 levels, is most likely slower. If we prepare: ``n = 200;
tree = Nest[0, 0, n];
path = Developer`FromPackedArray@ConstantArray[1, n];`` and compare `Extract[tree, path] // RepeatedTiming (* {2.5*10^-6, 0} *)` with `Module[{node = tree}, Do[node = node[[i]]; If[Head@node === 0, Break@0], {i, path}]] // RepeatedTiming(* {6.7*10^-6, 0} *)`

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე ... we'll see that even short-circuiting immediately at first level is slower than extraction of deepest zero. Such short-circuiting would be a good idea in some re-implementation in lower level language.

Comment: Spectacular! OK thanks again, I think I've exhausted all my questions

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I came back to this problem since I'm learning [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) and thought that this was an interesting problem to try in new language. So I have a Rust version, which probably is ugly over-complicated and unidiomatic, since it's my first Rust program, but it's pretty efficient. It goes to `40` in 2.5s using 1.4MB, - to `50` in 2 minutes using 13MB. I left it for the night on my laptop and it went to `64` from scratch in less than 7 hours using 325MB.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე If this problem is still of interest then [Rust code](https://github.com/jkuczm/tree_cache) and [precompiled binaries](https://github.com/jkuczm/tree_cache/releases) can be found on my GitHub.

Comment: @jkuczm Yes, definitely I am very interested. On my notebook (i7-6500U with 8gb ram on windows 10 x64) it just reached 50 in 125 seconds using 1.3mb, this is really spectacular! In fact in these 125 seconds it reached 38 and from that on it was VERY quick. How do you do this?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The fact that last elements are printed fast is a bit misleading, since program, by default, calculates all "`n`-th" cache elements, that will be needed for given maximal argument, before printing particular `f(n)`. For example if `f(50)` requires some cache elements with `n=25` they where already calculated before printing `f(25)` even if they where not needed by any `f(n)` up to, including, `f(49)`.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე If you want change order of calculations and before printing e.g. `f(25)` want to calculate only cache elements required by `f(25)` you can pass `-s` flag to the program. Due to how cache internally works this method will use slightly more memory.

Comment: @jkuczm I see. So then also memory used that is indicated after, say, `f(25)` when computing `f(50)` would be less if I would be computing, say, `f(40)`?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Without `-s` flag - yes, with `-s` flag - no.