# Generate numbers relatively prime with a given number

Tags: number-theory, code-request

I am interested in a function such that `f[m, i] = n` where `m, n` are positive integers and `n` is the `i`-th number relatively prime with `m`.

Getting a sample of the possible outputs of `f` is straightforward. For example, let `m = 30`. Now we can use

```
list = 2 Range[0,29] + 1;
list = Pick[list, GCD[30, list], 1]
(*{1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59}*)
```

where I'm picking from odd numbers since `m` happens to be even. There should be a pattern in these numbers given by `EulerPhi[30]` (this is `8`) and indeed, `list[[;;8]] + 30` coincides with `list[[9;;16]]`. How to continue from here?

Comment: What is the range of $ i $?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Arbitrary positive integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find relative primes, I've found `Complement` to be generally faster than `GCD` or `CoprimeQ`.

```
RelativePrimes[m_Integer] :=
   Complement[
      Range[m - 1],
      Apply[Sequence, Map[Range[#, m - 1, #] &, FactorInteger[m][[All, 1]]]]]
```

Your function `f` becomes the following.

```
f[m_, i_] :=
   Block[{n = RelativePrimes[m], e = EulerPhi[m]},
      n[[Mod[i, e, 1]]] + m * Quotient[i - 1, e]
   ]
SetAttributes[f,Listable]
```

Thus,

```
f[30,Range[20]]
```

> {1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59, 61,
>   67, 71, 73}

```
f[902,555]
```

> 1251

Answer (score 5):

I give a naive implementation

```
ithCoprime[m_, i_] := Module[{coprimes, j = 1},
                             coprimes = {1};
                             While[Length[coprimes] < i,
                                   j++;
                                   If[CoprimeQ[m, j], AppendTo[coprimes, j]]
                                  ];
                             Last[coprimes]
                            ]

ithCoprime[30, #] & /@ Range[16]
```

> ```
> {1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59}
> ```

---

**Update**

Here is a better version:

```
ithCoprime2[m_, i_] := Module[{j = 1, k = 1},
                              While[k < i, j++;
                                    If[CoprimeQ[m, j], k++]
                                   ];
                              j
                             ]
```

---

**Update 2**

Another version

```
ithCoprime3[m_, i_] := Module[{iterate, predicate, initial},
                              iterate = # + {1, Boole[CoprimeQ[m, First[#]]]} &;
                              predicate = Last[#] <= i &;
                              initial = {1, 1};
                              NestWhile[iterate, initial, predicate, 1, \[Infinity], -1][[1]]
                             ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f[m_, i_] := (
    m*#[[1]] + 
      Select[Range[m], GCD[#, m] == 1 &][[ #[[2]] ]] 
  )& [ QuotientRemainder[i, EulerPhi[m]] ]

RepeatedTiming[f[223 227, 4021987]]
(*  {0.058, 4057980}  *)
```

As long as `m` is not too big and you repeat `m`s, you can trade some memory for time.

```
fTable[m_] := fSmall[m] = 
  Select[Range[m], GCD[#, m] == 1 &];
f[m_, i_] := (m*#[[1]] + fTable[m][[#[[2]] ]]
  )& [ QuotientRemainder[i, EulerPhi[m]] ]

RepeatedTiming[f[223 227, 4021987]]
(*  {0.0000110, 4057980}  *)
```

If you are repeating `m`s, but you still have too many different `m`s, [discarding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19536/how-to-clear-parts-of-a-memoized-function) "old" `fTable`s is a good idea.